# Not Registered. Server returned "Method not allowed" (405)

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-12.04, asterisk, registration

I have successfully configured Asterisk Asterisk 10.12.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 & all the packages which were required has been installed successfully. Then i added an account in sip.conf file & added that account in SFlphone but it is not registering and giving the following error:

Not Registered. Server returned "Method not allowed" (405).

```
  [3001]
  type=friend
  context=default
  secret=3001
  host=dynamic
  nat=no
  canreinvite=no
  mailbox=1000@default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to debug asterisk sip protocol:

1)connect via ssh

2) type in:

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
core set verbose 10
```

check log.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem and solved it like this:

**what is the problem**?

*Asterisk SIP and SFL Phone are trying to use same port number 5060*

The *implication*: is your sip calls are looping back to the SFL phone rather than going to the asterisk server if the **SFLpone owns the port number** otherwise it wont work at all (*because you are telling the SFLpone to use port 5060 while another app is using it*).

**The solution**:

**1**.  *Stop both asterisk and **SFLphone***   make sure this by running this command: **sudo fuser -n udp 5060** , if there is any app running on this port you will see its process id and kill it (**sudo kill -9 pid**).

**2**.   Start **Asterisk** (*now asterisk will safely use the port 5060 for its SIP module*)

**3**.   Start your **SFLphone**.

**4**.   On your **SFLphone** goto *accounts* , then click *edit* for the account you are using. Then going to the *Advanced* tab change the *local port number* from *5060* (the default) to anything else (e.g *5062*).

**5**.   Now close the window and try to **register**

*If you are seeing another error let me hear that*.